# How do I override the page's CSS for a server-side control?

Tags: asp.net, css

My page uses a style sheet that sets td paddings to 0px.

My DataList's table and td properties are getting set by the style sheet and styles I set for the control (e.g. cellpadding 4 & cellspacing 4) are getting ignored.

I tried:

```
**Page.aspx**
<asp:DataList runat="server" ID="dlSomething" CssClass="DataList" 
CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="4">

**StyleSheet.css**
.DataList.td
{
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
}
```

But in the page source, I can see padding-top: 0 and padding-bottom: 0.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is not only with Server control. It can happen with any HTML element, if you have a general CSS definition and a specific CSS definition.

You need to override the first one with your specific CSS

```
  .DataList.td
    {
        padding-top: 4px !important;
        padding-bottom: 4px !important;
    }
```

http://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/

IF you use firebug (a firebug plugin) you can see which style definition are overriding your current style.

[image]

http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot. It turns out I had made a dumb typo in the css. There shouldn't be a period between .DataList and td: .DataList td. I thought of deleting the question, but your answer has useful information that might help others.